# handle unknown number of variables in Matlab or Mathematica

Tags: matlab, variables, wolfram-mathematica, symbols

I have an algorithm to produce an n by n matrix A for any given n. My goal is to find all solutions to the homogeneous system of linear equations A**x**=**0** using Matlab or Mathematica. I'm trying Matlab first.

Attempt 1: I can't use "linsolve" as A is likely to be singular. I want all the solutions.

Attempt 2: Use `solve(eqns, vars, 'ReturnConditions', true)`. However, how do I turn Ax into equation form? It seems that I need a for loop to put equations into the "eqns", but how can I define symbolic variables x1, x2, ..., xn? I don't know the value of n at first. Here is my psudo-code:

```
read (n);    
for i=1:n %% i_th equation
       eq=[];
       for j=1:n
         eq=eq+A[i,j]*x[j]; %% keep adding terms
       end
       eq=eq+['==0']; %% add '==0' to make it an equation
       eqns=eqns+eq %% add the ith equation to the equation list
 end
 vars=[];
 for i=1:n 
     vars=vars+x[i];
 end
 solve(eqns, vars, 'ReturnConditions', true)
```

Can you help making it a real Matlab or Mathematica code?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is made for linear algebra, so `A*x=0` is an equation with one, many or no vector `x` as a solution.

The problem with Matlab is, it has a great many ways to give you *one* solution but not to give *all* solutions.
The solution to the linear system `Ax=b` is usually obtained with `x = b\A` (where x will have the smallest L0 norm among all solutions, i.e. the fewest non-zero components) or `x=pinv(A)*b` (where x will have the smallest L2 norm among all solutions). See *pinv* [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pinv.html).

But in this specific case where `b=0` , both will give the trivial solution `x=0`

Now, seeking values of `x` such that `A*x=0` is nothing but looking for the kernel of matrix `A`. And Matlab [`null`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/null.html) function that does just that.